# $\sigma$-algebra generated by random variable

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am trying to understand the concept of a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a
random variable.

Consider the probability space $( [ 0, \infty), \mathcal{F},
P)$. Fix $A \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $P (A) \in (0, 1)$ and let $A^c$ be its complement. Fix $t_0 > 0$ and a
function $$X(t) = 1_{(t_0,\infty)}(t) . 1_A(t)$$

What is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$?

Comment: By $\chi_{\{t\gt t_0\}}$, do you mean that this is $1$ if $t\gt t_0$ and $0$ otherwise?  And what is $\mathcal F$?

Comment: Yes for the characteristic function. $\mathcal{F}$ is an arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra (not necessarily Borel).

Comment: Your notation is slightly mistakable: Do you consider the mapping $$t \mapsto 1_{(t_0,\infty)}(t) \cdot 1_A(t)$$  or $$[0,\infty) \ni s \mapsto 1_{(t_0,\infty)}(t) \cdot 1_A(s)$$ for some fixed $t$? Did's answer is about the second one whereas I considered the first mapping.

Comment: @saz It is the first one, but it is great to have two answers because I did not see that the notation could mean different things.

Comment: In the theory of stochastic processes, the notation $X_t$ is commonly used to denote a family of random variables, i.e. for each $t \geq 0$ there is a random variable $X_t: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry but nobody should use $X_t$ to denote the process $(X_t)_t$.

Comment: It seems that we are supposed to understand that one considers a single random variable $X$ defined on $\Omega=[0,\infty)$ by $X(t)=\mathbf 1_{t\gt t_0}\mathbf 1_A(t)$ for every $t$ in $\Omega$. This is in contradiction with the text of the question, but @saz answered *that* perfectly. Hence, answer deleted.

Comment: @Did You are right of course, it should read "used to denote an element of a family of random variables" instead... (And as you can check, my former answer looked exactly like yours.)

Comment: @Did I am sorry for the confusion in my question. But your answer was very illuminating for me. You should not have deleted it.

Comment: Undeleted. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not correct. Note that for any function $t \mapsto X(t) := X_t$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$ does not depend on $t$!

Let $B := A \cap (t_0,\infty)$. Then it follows from the definition that $$X_t = 1_B(t).$$ Consequently,

$$\sigma(X) := \sigma(X^{-1}(C); C \, \text{Borel}\} = \{\emptyset,\Omega,B,B^c\} = \{\emptyset,\Omega,A \cap (t_0,\infty), A^c \cup [0,t_0]\}$$

Answer (score 6):

The discussion in the comments to the OP indicates that one is supposed to understand that one considers a single random variable $X$ defined on $Ω=[0,+\infty)$ by $X(t)=\mathbf 1_{t>t_0}\mathbf 1_A(t)$ for every $t$ in $Ω$, or, equivalently, $$X=\mathbf 1_{A\cap(t_0,+\infty)}.$$ User @saz answered *that question*  perfectly. By contrast, the answer below is not relevant since it addresses the real text of the question, which states that, for every $t$, one considers some random variable $X_t$ defined on $Ω=[0,+∞)$ by $X_t(\omega)=\mathbf 1_{t>t_0}\mathbf 1_A(\omega)$ for every $\omega$ in $Ω$.

This explains why I deleted my answer, before undeleting it due to a comment by the OP.

---

Let $X_t=\mathbf 1_{t\gt t_0}\mathbf 1_A$ and $\sigma(X_t)$ the sigma-algebra generated by the random variable $X_t$.

- If $t\leqslant t_0$, then $X_t=0$ everywhere hence $\sigma(X_t)=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$.
- If $t\gt t_0$, then $X_t=\mathbf 1_A$ everywhere and $A\ne\varnothing$, $A\ne\Omega$ hence $\sigma(X_t)=\sigma(A)$, that is, $\sigma(X_t)=\{\varnothing,A,\Omega\setminus A,\Omega\}$.

The process $X=(X_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ is quite degenerate since there exists two random variables $Y$ and $Z$ such that $X_t=Y$ for every $t\leqslant t_0$ and  $X_t=Z$ for every $t\gt t_0$. Thus, the sigma-algebra $\sigma(X)$ generated by the whole process $X$ is $\sigma(Y,Z)$.

In the present case, $Y=0$ and $Z=\mathbf 1_A$ hence $\sigma(X)=\{\varnothing,A,\Omega\setminus A,\Omega\}$.